# What kind of PCA is best for my data?

Tags: pca, python, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I'm using sklearn to reduce the dimensionality of an object.This scan is 3D, with shape [15,15,15] and contains mostly zeros, altough the non-zero values are usally clustered together in some groups.

Examples of one slice out of the 3d object, all purple pixels are zeros:
[image] [image]

sklearn includes a list of several pca options:

1. [sklearn.decomposition.PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)
2. [truncated SVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html#sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD)
3. [sparse PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.SparsePCA.html)

From what I understand, my object is considerd "sparse" since most of its values are zero. Also, I'm flattening this object into a vector before reducing it.  what pca kind - or dimensionality reduction in general - is best for this kind of objects?